# Why Data Trigger is not firing

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a XAML code. I am trying to fill the rectangle on Datatrigger but its not firing

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedEnrollments}" Visibility="{Binding EnrollmentsExist, Converter={x:Static s:BooleanToVisibilityConverter.Default}, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <RadioButton Tag="{Binding Id}" GroupName="Enrollments" ToolTip="{Binding Title}" Checked="EnrollmentRadioButton_Checked" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}">
                <RadioButton.ContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                            <TextBlock TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" 
                                       Text="{Binding ToolTip, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=RadioButton}}" />
                            <Rectangle x:Name="RankIcon" Width="30">
                                <Rectangle.Style>
                                    <Style>
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Rank}" Value="Primary">
                                                <Setter  Property="Rectangle.Fill" Value="Blue"></Setter>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Rank}" Value="Secondary">
                                                <Setter  Property="Rectangle.Fill" Value="{DynamicResource IconRankSecondary}"></Setter>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </Rectangle.Style>
                            </Rectangle>
                         </StackPanel>
                        <DataTemplate.Triggers>

                        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </RadioButton.ContentTemplate>
            </RadioButton>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Please help anypne

Comment: does the `Rank` property fire a `PropertyChangedEvent` ?

Comment: Yes it fires Propertychanged Event

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the setters so that they use Property="Fill" instead of Property="Rectangle.Fill"

Answer (score 0):

Move the data trigger into the resources of the page or view. I believe that it may be firing but the binding for Value="{DynamicResource IconRankSecondary}" may be unable to find the DynamicResource.

Verify Databinding issues by running it in debug mode and looking at the debug output specifying binding failures.

Comment: On First DataTrigger I am trying to fill Rectangle with Blue color.... even that is also not happening.. Its not related to DynamicResource thing.

Comment: @NavneetDuggal in the above textbox, temporarily bind the text to Rank and see if it displays what you expect.

Comment: you are right... binding text to Rank doesn't display anything, I tried relative source also to get to the Itemssource of ItemsControl but still nothing is getting displayed

Comment: @NavneetDuggal Ok, now take my recommendation to move the style into the page's resource. That way the style can access the page's datacontext (that is what I assume you are binding to) outside of what the controls datacontext is getting.